# linking with two symbols. one defined in an archive file

Tags: c++, googletest

I noticed that gtest provides a way to link again `gtest_main` so that end user doesn't need to write their own `main` function. This works in the following way. (A small example file named `hello.cpp`)

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(Hello, Basic) {}
```

One can compile this with:

```
g++ hello.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main
```

and everything works out fine. The reason this works is that there is a `main` function defined in gtest_main.cc from which the `libgtest_main.a` is generated.

Now here is the thing. If I change my `hello.cpp` to

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(Hello, Basic) {}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

everything still works with the same command line! There are two `main` symbols now, and the linker has conveniently chosen the one main function which I defined in my `hello.cpp`.

What is the magic going on here?

Comment: _the linker has conveniently chosen the one main function which I defined in my `hello.cpp`_ How did you know? You could do an extra output into your `main()` to be sure. Did you analyze the objects and binary somehow to see what finally was really linked in? (This is not meant as critics. I'm just curious.)

Comment: @Scheff yes, I added a print statement in my main to verify that it was indeed my main that was being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No magic is going on. What you have observed is the normal default behaviour of
the linker.

A static library `libxy.a` is an [`ar` archive](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) of
object files `x.o`, `y.o`,...

If an object file `x.o` appears in the linker inputs of a program, the linker links it
into the program *unconditionally*.

If a static library `libxy.a` appears in the linker inputs, the linker examines the
archive to find any object files that provide definitions for symbols that have
already been referenced, but not already defined, in files already linked into
the program. It extracts just those object files, if any, from the archive and links
*them* into the program exactly as if they were individually named linker inputs
and the static library was not mentioned at all.

The usual reason that we offer a set of object files to the linker in a static library,
rather than as individual inputs, is *so that* the linker will select just the ones
it *needs* to obtain definitions for unresolved symbol references, rather than simply
linking all of them into the program whether they are needed or not.

Here is a elementary illustration in C<sup>1</sup>:-

**main.c**

```
extern void x(void);

int main(void)
{
    x();
    return 0;
}
```

**lib_main.c**

```
extern void y(void);

int main(void)
{
    y();
    return 0;
}
```

**x.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void x(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**y.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void y(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

Compile all those to object files:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c lib_main.c x.c y.c
```

Make a static library containing `lib_main.o`, `x.o` and `y.o`:

```
$ ar rcs libmxy.a lib_main.o x.o y.o
```

Link a program `prog` like this:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libmxy.a
```

It runs like:

```
$ ./prog
x
```

So the definition of `main` provided by `main.o` was linked and the other
definition of `main` in `libmxy.a(lib_main.o)` was ignored. Repeating the linkage
with some diagnostics sheds more light.

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libmxy.a -Wl,-trace,-trace-symbol=main,-trace-symbol=x
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
main.o
(libmxy.a)x.o
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: reference to main
main.o: definition of main
main.o: reference to x
libmxy.a(x.o): definition of x
```

The `-trace` option asks the linker to show us what files were actually used in
the linkage. `-trace-symbol=name` asks the linker to show us the files in which
symbol `name` was defined or referenced. Most of the files linked are boilerplate
that `gcc` adds to the linker commandline by default. The ones that *we* built are:

```
main.o
(libmxy.a)x.o
```

The linker found the symbol `main` first referenced in the boilerplate object
file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o`. Then
it found a definition of `main` in the object file `main.o`, which was linked
unconditionally. That resolved `main`. The linker didn't search `libmxy.a` for
another definition of `main` because it didn't need one.

In `main.o` it found an undefined reference to `x` and the next linker input
was `libmxy.a`. So it seached the object files in that archive for one that
defines `x`. It found `libmxy.a(x.o)` and extracted and linked it. Then it was
done.

The other object files that we *offered* to the linker in `libmxy.a`:

```
libmxy.a(lib_main.o)
libmxy.a(y.o)
```

were not needed. They might as well not have existed. The linkage is exactly
the same as:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o x.o
$ ./prog
x
```

**What is more interesting about `libgtest_main.a`...**

... is the fact that here you have a static library that contains a member (`libgtest_main.a(gtest_main.cc.o)`) that *will be linked*
into your program even if your linkage does not input *any* object files before
`libgtest_main.a`:

```
$ g++ -o prog -lgtest_main -pthread
```

links successfully, and `prog` will run just to say that it has nothing to do.
If `-lgtest_main` is the very first linker input, then when the linker considers
it, it cannot have discovered any undefined references in files already linked,
since there are none, and therefore has no need to link any object file within
`libgtest_main.a`. But it does, and that behaviour might be described as a bit of
magic.

But we've already seen the explanation in the diagnostic output of:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o libmxy.a -Wl,-trace,-trace-symbol=main,-trace-symbol=x
```

which informed us that `main` is first referenced in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o`.

That boilerplate object file is the GCC C runtime startup code, which performs standard initializations for program
execution and finishes by calling `main`. This is an *object file*, so it will be linked
unconditionally, and GCC places it *before* all other inputs in the generated linker commandline. Link in verbose
mode (`gcc -v ...`) to see that. So in fact there is *always* an object file, first in the program's linkage,
that makes reference to `main`, no matter what object files you explicitly link. And if you
do not yourself input an object file that defines `main` before you input libraries, then
the linker *will* search libraries for a definition of `main`. `libgtest_main` exploits that fact.

Of course, it is only practical to exploit this fact for googletest because for all normal
programs that link googletest, the definition of `main` is *identical*.

---

[1] The choice of C rather than C++ makes no difference, except that in C we
don't have to bother about name-mangling.

Comment: I felt something like this and I remember roughly that I learnt that (round about 25 years ago) when I was teached that the Motif library (`-lXm`) has to be inserted into link line before X11 and Xt (`-lXt -lX11`) for that reason (as Motif seems to "override" something of the others) but that's all that far away that I didn't dare to mention it. (Concerning Motif, I googled and found a conversation that proved me right but without any specific reason why.)